# A problem of topology about connectedness

Tags: general-topology

Consider a topology $T$ on $\mathbb{R}$:{The all open sets in  $\mathbb{R}$ not containing $0$} union { $\mathbb{R}$}.Then which of the following is true?

$1.T$ is connected.

$2.T$ is hausdorff.

I have proved $T$ is not hausdorff.Is it correct?Also I have problem about the first option I do not know whether it is connected or not.

Answer (score 3):

Well $(X,T)$ is obviously not Hausdorff since the only neighborhood of $0$ is $\mathbb{R}$.
For the same reason, $(X,T)$ is connected since any separation of it into two open disjoint sets implies that one of the sets contains $0$ and is therefore the entire line!

Answer (score 1):

You have one element in $\mathbb{R}$ that is not in union anytwo of elements of $\mathcal{T}$

What is that??

Does this say something is wrong if i write $\mathbb{R}=M\cup V$ with $M,N\in \mathcal{T}$??